# The correct way to await inside a foreach loop

Tags: c#, async-await, c#-8.0, ef-core-3.0, iasyncenumerable

Is this the correct way to use foreach loops whist using async ? Is there a better more efficient way? IAsyncEnumerable?
(Ignore the fact that the two tables could be joined together this is a simple example)

```
public async Task<IList<ContactAndAccounts>> GetAll()
{
    var accounts = await _dbContext.Account.Where(x => x.Name == "Amazing").ToListAsync();

    foreach(var account in accounts)
    {
           accounts.Contacts = await GetContact(account.Id);
    }

    return accounts;
}

public async Task<IList<contact>> GetContact(Guid id)
{
    return await _dbContext.Contact.Where(x => x.AccountLinkId = id).ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't get the contacts in separate queries anyway. Why don't you `Include` them?

Comment: The problem here has nothing to do with await and loops. It's the missing relation. The fix is to use `Include(acc=>acc.Contacts)`. `Account` should have a `Contacts` property and the DbContext should contain the 1-to-many relation

Comment: With a correct dbcontext, the query becomes just `_dbContext.Account.Include(acc=>acc.Contatcts).Where(...).ToListAsync()`. No looping is needed

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i agree but please read the original questions "Ignore the fact that the two tables could be joined together this is a simple example"

Comment: That's the main problem, it can't be ignored. Everything else is band-aids. This won't solve the real problem. The correct fix is *easier* than every one of the solutions posted here

Comment: @Rhodes73 the only answer that mitigates the problem is Michael Hancock's - at least load all contacts in a single query instead of running 100 separate queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with [Johnathan Barclay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59984661/6306281) but would say that from a database perspective you might find it is faster to do a single query big query than lots of small queries.

Doing one query and passing in all of your ids is usually less expensive than multiple seperate queries.

```cs
public async Task<IList<ContactAndAccounts>> GetAll()
{
    var accounts = await _dbContext.Account.Where(x => x.Name == "Amazing").ToListAsync();

    var contacts = await GetContacts(accounts.Select(o => o.Id));

    // Map contacts to accounts in memory

    return accounts;
}

public async Task<IList<contact>> GetContacts(List<Guid> ids)
{
    return await _dbContext.Contact.Where(x => ids.Contain(x.AccountLinkId)).ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: Yes, I was focusing on the `foreach` loop and didn't notice this. +1

Comment: The *real* solution would be to add a relation between `Account` and `Contact` and use `Include(acc=>acc.Contacts)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Short of this OP could do a join if no naviagtion property exists. But I always find they can end up looking rather messy in Linq.

Comment: Which is why the relation must be added. Everything else is band-aids. The code in all answers is already a lot more complicated than a correct LINQ query would be

Comment: If you take a look at this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/17068), you will see that currently there is a huge difference in what is supported for collection navigation properties and `GroupJoin`s  (although technically they should be equivalent). Which makes usage of navigation properties almost mandatory.

Comment: That is strange, you would think the generated query would be effectively the same!

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely not the most efficient way.

Each `await` causes the loop to pause until the `Task` is complete.

You want to allow all the tasks to run simultaneously:

```
public async Task<IList<ContactAndAccounts>> GetAll()
{
    var accounts = await _dbContext.Account.Where(x => x.Name == "Amazing").ToListAsync();

    await Task.WhenAll(accounts.Select(async account => 
    {
        accounts.Contact = await GetContact(account.Id);
    }));

    return accounts;
}
```

`Select` will yield a `Task` for each item, which can be awaited through `Task.WhenAll`.

Comment: Yes WhenAll is the way to go. Congrats you were faster than I :)

Comment: This still executes 101 queries when only 1 is needed. Running the 100 queries in parallel won't improve performance, it will increase lock contention

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes, I notice that now, but I answered the question at hand. Michael has elaborated on that already in his answer.

Answer (score -2):

> Is there a better more efficient way? IAsyncEnumerable?

Yes! Change signature and replace `accounts.Contacts = await GetContact(account.Id);` with `yield return await GetContract(account.Id)`.

Comment: That's not more efficient. The fundamental problem is that the related objects are loaded one by one using different queries instead of a single query that loads all of them at once. IAsyncEnumerable won't fix that